# Сделать git pull с помощью gitlab-runner

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, непрерывная-интеграция

У нас развёрнут self-hosted Gitlab, плюс есть отдельный сервер с нашим веб-приложением, и на этом же сервере с веб-приложением развернут гитлаб раннер на shell executor. При попытке сделать `git pull` раннером вылезает такая ошибка:

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/path/to/project'
```

Владелец директории с проектом - `root`. Нужно как-то дать возможность раннеру вызывать `git pull` через `sudo` без пароля, при этом не давая пользователю gitlab-runner больше прав чем нужно

Comment: Исправьте владельца папки с проектом на того пользователя, под которым раннер выполняет сборку. Никих root и sudo.

Comment: @user7860670 попробую, спасибо

Comment: @user7860670 не помогло, поменял владельца с помощью `chown gitlab-runner /path/to/project`, владелец изменился, но ошибка та же

Comment: Эта команда не поменяла владельцев содержимого, на что может жаловаться git. Вообще-то было бы проще удалить папку и дать раннеру ее перескачать заново. Кроме того (если папка и так была ранее скачена им), проблема может быть в том, что последующие операции производятся под другим пользователем.